# How can I copy or set the language setting of a document?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am developing an add-on that changes the active document based on a template document that the user selects. Template documents exist with different language settings. How can I copy the language setting from the template document to the active document? Or if that is not possible, how could I just set the language of the active document?

Comment: Are you referring to a script within a spreadsheet? if yes, you can use `setSpreadsheetLocale()` https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#setspreadsheetlocalelocale

Comment: No, my question is about documents, not spreadsheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it is currently not possible to get or set the language of a document. Several requests have been made to Google to make this possible. See issues 4886, 5060 and 6006 on https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues.